# How do I parse out data out of a field before a slash

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In MS-SQL 2008 I have a varchar field that holds data. It will have names like this:

1. John/Cindy
2. Steve
3. Jack/Joe

I need the data to read in my output like this (so gathering the first name listed only if there are multiple separated by a slash):

1. John
2. Steve
3. Jack

I am assuming this needs to be some type of function but not sure. Appreciate the help, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have very good string manipulation functions, but this isn't so hard:

```
select (case when names like '%/%'
             then left(names, charindex('/', names) - 1)
             else names
        end)
```

EDIT:

Mikael's suggestion saves the `case` statement:

```
select left(names + '/', charindex('/', names) - 1)
```

Comment: Could you not just add LEN(Names) - the charindex to get rid of the case statement?

Comment: @cronos2546 . . . I'm not sure what you mean.  `CHARINDEX()` returns `0` if the value is not found, and that is invalid for substring operations.

Comment: @cronos2546 One way to avoid the case statement is to add a `/` to the end of the string just to make sure it is always there. `left(T.Name, charindex('/', T.Name+'/')-1)`.